# React/Redux can't iterate over array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm in the process of learning React/Redux and I've run into an issue while converting a single page web app of mine to the framework/paradigm. What i'm trying to do is let the initial state of the web app have an array that is to be populated by objects from an API request, this array is called "makes". I want to do this so I can display "makes" from the API on the first page of the website upon it loading. This can be seen in the `index.js` file below:

```
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import configureStore from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

let makesUrl = 'the url to the API'
let cached = cache.get(makesUrl)
let makes = []

// Future cache setup.
if(!cached) {
    console.log("NOT CACHED")
}
else {
    console.log("CACHED")
}

// Get the makes via API.
fetch(makesUrl).then((response) => {
    // Pass JSON to the next 'then'
    return response.json()
}).then((json) => {
    json.makes.forEach((make) => {
        makes.push(make)
    })
})

let initialState = {
  grids: [],
  makes: makes
}

let store = configureStore(initialState)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The `state` and `dispatch` are mapped to the props and passed down to the components that need them in my `App.js` file as such:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import './App.css'
import Head from './components/Head'
import Middle from './components/Middle'
import Foot from './components/Foot'
import actions from './redux/actions'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Head />
          <div className="middle container">
            <Middle actions={this.props.actions} makes={this.props.makes}/>
          </div>
          <Foot />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

At all points, in the chrome dev tools, I can see that the API call was successful and the state is shown to have `makes: Array[62]` with 62 objects inside, however if I console log the length of the array in the component that these makes are passed down to as seen below, it says the length is 0, and each index of the array is undefinded.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class MakeButtons extends Component {

        handleClick(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            console.log("CLICK")
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    {
                        console.log(this.props.makes.length)
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default MakeButtons
```

This is essentially what I've been trying to figure out for the past couple hours, so I can use the `forEach` or `map` function to return links/buttons for each of the objects in the array, however at the moment this does not work, despite dev tools showing the state to be normal. Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are initializing your app before the fetch is back. Furthermore, you should make the init call an action/reducer, that will make this process *much* cleaner and your app won't have to hang based on the first fetch call.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Ah that makes sense! Would the componentWillMount method be appropriate in this situation to dispatch an action?

Comment: Yes, either componentWillMount or componentDidMount because they are only called once upon loading your app. You create an action with your async call that updates the state and call it in one of those two.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: No problem! If you need help, or would like me to answer this question with an example of that, let me know and I will set one up for you.

Comment: @ajmajmajma That would be great, as I'm a little bit confused on how it would actually look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you really just need to set up an action/reducer for your init, then you can call it in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` because they are only called once upon loading your app.

In the way you are doing it now you have a fetch and an app using the data from the fetch that is *not* waiting for the async call to finish before it starts the app.

You just want to create your init action, so your action creator would be something like :

```
   import * as services from './services';

   function initMyAppDispatcher(type, data, status) {
       return {
          type, 
          data,
          status
        };
   }


   export function initMyApp(dispatch, makesUrl) {
      dispatch(initMyAppDispatcher(actions.INIT_APP, {}, 'PENDING');

      return services.myInitCall(makesUrl)
         .then((data) =>
             dispatch(initMyAppDispatcher(actions.INIT_APP, data, 'SUCCESS'),
            (error) =>
             dispatch(initMyAppDispatcher(actions.INIT_APP, error, 'FAILURE'),
         )
         .catch(yourErrorHandling);
   }
```

Services.myInitCall is however you want to implement it, just make sure you export it back as a promise. In your case you can replace that line with `fetch(makesUrl)` as long as you have access to it there. Then having it set up like this, you can set your reducers like so :

```
   case actions.INIT_APP:
            if (action.status) {
                switch (action.status) {
                    case PENDING:
                        //you can use this to create a "loading" state like a spinner or whatever
                        return state;
                    case SUCCESS:
                        // note: this is immutablejs syntax, use whatever you prefer
                        return state.set('makes', action.data);
                   case FAILURE:
                        return state;

                    default:
                        return state;
                }
            }
            return state;
```

One thing to note is I have dispatch in my action creators because I use `mapDispatchToProps` in place of `mapToProps`. So your container looks something like this :

```
import * as actionCreators from './action-creators';

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        makes: state.get('makes')
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        initMyApp: actionCreators.initMyApp.bind(null, dispatch)
    };
}


export default function(component = Component) {
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
}
```

then in your component `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, pass in and call your init function

```
   componentDidMount() {
       this.props.initMyApp();

   }
```